# What is the difference between runApp(new MyApp()) and runApp(new MaterialApp()) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In flutter we can pass a stateless widget that returns a `MaterialApp` instance to the `runApp()` function like this:

```
void main()=>runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

or we can pass the instance of `MaterialApp` directly to the `runApp()` function like so:

```
void main()=>runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
       ...
    );
);
```

What is the difference between these to ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no difference in visual behavior.
What changes is how hot reload behaves.

For example if you used `runApp(MaterialApp())`, changing from

```
runApp(MaterialApp(title: 'Foo'))
```

to

```
runApp(MaterialApp(title: 'Bar'))
```

then the hot reload wouldn't take changes into consideration.

While if you had the following class :

```
class MyApp {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Foo',
    );
  )
}
```

and used it like this :

```
runApp(MyApp())
```

then changing `title` of `MyApp` would be correctly hot reloaded.

Comment: Yes. Because of the `build()` method, that make sense thanks.

Comment: No this is because hot reload doesn't run `main` again. It simply edit the modified classes and refresh the screen with the new code. But in the end, `runApp` isn't called again with new props.

Answer (score 2):

For hot-reload to be able to keep the state, it applies code changes and re-runs `build()` so that the view is updated. If the whole app would be restarted, the previous state would be lost. This is not desired. If you want this use **hot restart** instead.

This also means that changes to code that is only executed when the whole app is restarted, will not be applied to the current state.

For more details about hot-reload and limitations see https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/hot-reload

To add custom behavior on hot-reload the method `State<T>.reassemble` can be overridden https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/reassemble.html

Answer (score 1):

In one case you have a class, which you can add more methods to, and use them. In one case you don't.

Comment: While this is correct for production mode, the real purpose if for development (hot reload)