# Flutter: Hot reload and Routes

Tags: routes, dart, flutter, hot-reload

I noticed that when I extend MaterialPageRoutes and then instance them like this

```
class Route extends MaterialPageRoute {
  Route(): super(
    builder: (context) {
      return SomeWidget();
    }
  );
}
...somewhere in the build method of another class...
Navigator.push(context, Route())
```

a hot-reload will not rebuild the contents of the route like it does when I do

```
...somewhere in the build method of another class...
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) {
    return SomeWidget();
  }
))
```

or

```
class Route extends MaterialPageRoute {
  Route(): super(
    builder: (context) {
      return RouteWidget();
    }
  );
}
class RouteWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SomeWidget();
  }
}
...somewhere in the build method of another class...
Navigator.push(context, Route())
```

I find it especially weird that the last work-around works. Any idea what I'm missing? The documentation says that a hot-reload will rebuild all widgets.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312843/what-is-the-difference-between-runappnew-myapp-and-runappnew-materialapp/51313000#51313000

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Does this count for every object or just the first given to runApp()? Because if the latter is the case, then this is not the cause for me.

Comment: It counts torward anything that is _not_ returned by `build`. So routes, overlays, ...

Comment: Ok, thanks! Don't forget to post your comments as an answer so that I can mark it, if you care about that.

Answer (score 0):

Hot-reload applies the code changes and re-runs `build()` so that the view is updated. To reload the Route, a hot restart will be needed.

For more details about hot-reload, see: https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/hot-reload